# How to make disabled @Html.DropDownListFor form fields will submit to the server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have this working peace of code, which displays and populate a DropDownList which is disabled in my MVC4 Razor Web App.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LIFELINECODE, new SelectList(ViewBag.LifeLinePickList, "Text", "Value"), new { @class = "form-control chosen-select", @disabled = "disabled" })
```

But disabled form fields not submitted to the server. Please give me some other Suggestions to achieve my requirement.

I have another DropdownList in that Same page. The first drop-down is disables, and the other one will always enables.
When i submit the button, i enables the First dropdown with below code.

```
 $(function () {
            $("#btnSave").click(function () {
                $("#LIFELINECODE").removeAttr("disabled");
            });
        });
```

If suppose the Second dropdown doesn't meet mandatory check, it showing Validation. How can i check the Model Validations is Succeeded or not, before disabling attributes of First drop-down by JQuery.

Please give me suggestions.

Comment: just call a function on submit button and make dropdown disabled false and then submit form...that will work fine.

Comment: Whats the point of a a disabled select (you cant select anything)? You could use `@Html.HiddenFor()` for postback and `@Html.DisplayFor()` for display.